# Leaflet Zoom on WMS-Layers - Error: Attempted to load an infinite number of tiles GridLayer.js

Tags: leaflet, wms, zoom

I use Leaflet 1.5.1 for showing WMS layers on a GeoServer 2.15.1. I can only zoom up to zoom level 14. If I continue to zoom into the map, I see the following error message.

```
Error: Attempted to load an infinite number of tiles GridLayer.js:658:44
```

I found this: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/6416
But I am sure, that is not the problem for me. I set zoom correcly.

Do I have to pay attention to zooming WMS layers?

Edit:
I noticed the mistake myself.

I defined a CRS

```
    var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:25833',
        '+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs',
        {
            resolutions: [
                8192, 4096, 
                2048, 1024, 512, 256, 
                128, 64, 32, 16, 
                8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5, 
                0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, 0.03125,
                0.015625, 0.0078125
            ],
            origin: [0, 0]
        })
```

and I made a mistake. I used in the last two resolutions a comma as the decimal separator instead of the dot. The entry `0,015625, 0,0078125` instead of `0.015625, 0.0078125` leads to the error message.

Comment: Seeing the code that causes this would be helpful.

Comment: I noticed the mistake myself.
I defined a CRS and I made a mistake. I used in the last two resolutions a comma as the decimal separator instead of the dot. The entry `0,015625, 0,0078125` instead of `0.015625, 0.0078125` leads to the error message.

Comment: Rather than editing your question to contain the answer, you could have edited it to contain the problem, and answered it yourself. At this point, I'd vote for a "not reproducible" close reason.